# Amazon Cloudwatch log filtering - JSON syntax

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda function which is logging errors.  Errors are logged as such:

`console.error(err);`

I'm trying to create a Cloudwatch filter which uses their JSON log filtering syntax:

`{ $.errorType = "ValidationException" }`

I can see the error in the log

`2015-11-24T20:26:02.852Z    76800706-2d78-45ed-9068-46ccccafe6af
{
    "errorMessage": "1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'xxxxxx' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1",
    "errorType": "ValidationException",
    "stackTrace": [
...etc...
    ]
}`

Is there some sort of special setup or manual logging into CloudWatch required to support the JSON filter syntax?  I cannot find any info in the CloudWatch docs.

Docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#d0e19372

Answer (score 0):

Seems like when you log from Lambda it turns everything in to a string. May have something to do with adding the Request time and ID to each item.