# How to filter CloudWatch logs from Lambda with a JSON Metric Filter

Tags: json, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Using the example straight from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html), in a lambda function I put:

```
console.log(
        {
          "eventType": "UpdateTrail",
          "sourceIPAddress": "111.111.111.111",
          "arrayKey": [
                "value",
                "another value"
          ],
          "objectList": [
               {
                 "name": "a",
                 "id": 1
               },
               {
                 "name": "b",
                 "id": 2
               }
          ],
          "SomeObject": null,
          "ThisFlag": true
        })
```

I then create a logs metric filter in CloudWatch with a filter pattern as specified in the docs example:

```
{ $.eventType = "UpdateTrail" }
```

The filter doesn't generate a metric like the documentation says it should - here's the output:

```
2017-10-23T13:27:19.320Z    1143e2b0-eea6-4225-88c0-efcd79055f7b    { eventType: 'UpdateTrail',
sourceIPAddress: '111.111.111.111',
arrayKey: [ 'value', 'another value' ],
objectList: [ { name: 'a', id: 1 }, { name: 'b', id: 2 } ],
SomeObject: null,
ThisFlag: true }
```

So as you can see the timestamp and the identifier are prepended to the JSON.

An answer in [Amazon Cloudwatch log filtering - JSON syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903735/amazon-cloudwatch-log-filtering-json-syntax) says it is because Lambda turns logs into a string. [How to parse mixed text and JSON log entries in AWS CloudWatch for Log Metric Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556966/how-to-parse-mixed-text-and-json-log-entries-in-aws-cloudwatch-for-log-metric-fi) says much the same. A solution isn't offered in either case. How do you filter CloudWatch logs from Lambda with a JSON Metric Filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at what the log line actually looks like. If you see something like this, it's not a valid json:

```
{ eventType: 'UpdateTrail', ... }
```

What you want is something like this (note the quotation):

```
{ "eventType": "UpdateTrail", ...}
```

To get that, try to wrap your object in `JSON.stringify()`, like this:

```
console.log(
        JSON.stringify(
            {
              "eventType": "UpdateTrail",
              "sourceIPAddress": "111.111.111.111",
              "arrayKey": [
                    "value",
                    "another value"
              ],
              "objectList": [
                   {
                     "name": "a",
                     "id": 1
                   },
                   {
                     "name": "b",
                     "id": 2
                   }
              ],
              "SomeObject": null,
              "ThisFlag": true
            }
        )
    )
```

Comment: That was it. I've added the invalid JSON log output to the question description. I didn't catch that it was invalid and needed to be stringified. Should have just tried that early on. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903735/amazon-cloudwatch-log-filtering-json-syntax does have valid JSON without the stringify - any idea why the difference? Yet apparently the filter didn't generate an event.

Comment: That question is almost 2 years old, could be that something changed in CloudWatch Logs or Lambda in the meantime.